# SSH login does not work after enabling 2-factor. Getting failed to read ".google_authenticator"

Tags: server, ssh, authentication, google, two-factor-authentication

I have a server running Ubuntu 20.04 and I wanted to try to set up 2 factor authentication to secure SSH logins.

I logged in to my server, and followed this tutorial: `https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-set-up-multi-factor-authentication-for-ssh-on-ubuntu-20-04/` (EDIT: I deliberately removed the hyperlink because I don't recommend the tutorial. use [Ubuntu's official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/configure-ssh-2fa) instead)

The thing I did differently is that I used my own user (not root), which has sudo privileges. So instead of doing `apt-get install libpam-google-authenticator -y`, I did `sudo apt-get install libpam-google-authenticator -y`, etc.

I tried to sign out, and then I try to sign in again but it doesn't work. It asks me for a password over and over

```
~$ ssh birger@10.0.0.10
Password:     <- I enter the password and hit ENTER
Password:     <- I enter the password and hit ENTER
Password:     <- I enter the password and hit ENTER
birger@10.0.0.10's password:     <- I enter the password and hit ENTER
Permission denied, please try again.
birger@10.0.0.10's password:     <- I enter the password and hit ENTER
Received disconnect from 10.0.0.10 port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from 10.0.0.10 port 22
```

I tried looking at the log file `/var/log/auth.log` and I notice these lines which I thought were relevant:

```
sshd(pam_google_authenticator) [9164]:Failed to read "/home/birger/.google_authenticator" for "birger"
sshd[9162]: error: PAM: Authentication faile for birger from 10.0.0.254
```

So my question is why does the SSH login fail, after I enabled Google 2-factor? What can I do to fix this? I tried looking for the file `/home/birger/.google_authenticator` that was mentioned in the log but it does not exist...

Luckily I have physical access to the server, so I can connect a monitor and keyboard to it and then I can log in with standard, local login.

Comment: Did you run `google-authenticator` under your user on the remote server which *creates* that file, as the instructions state and NOT use sudo when executing it?  Installing the authentication plugin is only part of it - you have to generate the seed code/file with the `google-authenticator` program on your user via SSH *before* you enable the plugin in enforcing mode.

Comment: Hmm, your suspicion was correct. It seems I ran `sudo google-authenticator`, now I tried it without `sudo` and the file is there with data. Still not able to log in though, getting `error: PAM: User account has expired for birger from 10.0.0.254`

Comment: Nevermind, it's fixed now. Thanks @ThomasWard

Comment: @user68186 after i'm done with my FT job i'll make it an answer.  Patience ;)

Comment: @ThomasWard I have retracted my close vote. Three cheers for the FT job! :D

Comment: I have the same issue on a Debian 11 machine, but insted of running `sudo google_authenticator` I only did `google_authenticator` and I can't enter my password, it always says Access denied while trying to enter my pw. Can somebody have an other solution for this?

Comment: @Jessica perhaps it is best if you create a new question for that issue